# Auto sign in OWA web part using c# in sharepoint 2010

Tags: development

I need the OWA web part to automatically login the current user.
How to do so using C#

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't something you can develop a solution for unless you are looking to build your own Single Sign-On solution (not recommended).  Take a look at [this other thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65242/owa-single-sign-on-through-iframe) that outlines two options (Kerberos delegation or ADFS).

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this post and my answer.

[Sharepoint 2010 / Exchange 2010 Single Sign On issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54267/sharepoint-2010-exchange-2010-single-sign-on-issue/54276#54276)

If the user accessing SharePoint is the same account for the OWA access it is all a matter of configuration for the client and the servers (Exchange and SharePoint).

If you have the need to do it via code this will be a pretty big effort you will have to take with deep knowledge of kerberos and ad in general.